# WaveSpawner in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a wave spawner script from a video i saw, since I'm fairly new to this still and its just more so a learning experience than anything really, but when spawning in the zombies im quite confused why the Wave Countdown is stuck and not counting down after i have killed them all to go onto another wave? the code for the wavespawner im using is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WaveSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum SpawnState { SPAWNING, WAITING, COUNTING };

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Wave
    {
        public string name;
        public Transform enemy;
        public int count;
        public float rate;
    }

    public Wave[] waves;
    public int nextWave = 1;
    public int NextWave
    {
        get { return nextWave + 1; }
    }

    public Transform[] spawnPoints;

    public float timeBetweenWaves = 5f;
    public float waveCountdown;
    public float WaveCountdown
    {
        get { return waveCountdown; }
    }

    private float searchCountdown = 1f;

    private SpawnState state = SpawnState.COUNTING;
    public SpawnState State
    {
        get { return state; }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (spawnPoints.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No spawn points referenced.");
        }

        waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (state == SpawnState.WAITING)
        {
            if (!EnemyIsAlive())
            {
                WaveCompleted();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (waveCountdown <= 1)
        {
            if (state != SpawnState.SPAWNING)
            {
                StartCoroutine( SpawnWave ( waves[nextWave] ) );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            waveCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    void WaveCompleted()
    {
        Debug.Log("Wave Completed!");

        state = SpawnState.COUNTING;
        waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves;

        if (nextWave + 1 > waves.Length - 1)
        {
            nextWave = 0;
            Debug.Log("ALL WAVES COMPLETE! Looping...");
        }
        else
        {
            nextWave++;
        }
    }

    bool EnemyIsAlive()
    {
        searchCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (searchCountdown <= 0f)
        {
            searchCountdown = 1f;
            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy") == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnWave(Wave _wave)
    {
        Debug.Log("Spawning Wave: " + _wave.name);
        state = SpawnState.SPAWNING;

        for (int i = 0; i < _wave.count; i++)
        {
            SpawnEnemy(_wave.enemy);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds( 1f/_wave.rate );
        }

        state = SpawnState.WAITING;

        yield break;
    }

    void SpawnEnemy(Transform _enemy)
    {
        Debug.Log("Spawning Enemy: " + _enemy.name);

        Transform _sp = spawnPoints[ Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length) ];
        Instantiate(_enemy, _sp.position, _sp.rotation);
    }

}
```

if anyone has any ideas as to why or knows what the problem is it would really help

Comment: Hi, seems like you never reset `waveCountdown`
Also, this seems a little bit complicated for what you are trying to achieve. Maybe try to put the problem down on paper and isolate the important parts :)

Comment: what do you mean i never reset waveCountdown? it wasn't from me xD thats from a brackeys video so thats why i figured it would be okay

Comment: In your update method, `if (waveCountdown <= 1)` you call `SpawnWave`, but spawnWave never reset waveCountdown to `timeBetweenWaves` like you initialy do in the start method.
Also, if you don't understand what you are doing, don't expect us to solve it ahah, just trying to help !

Comment: no dont expect anyone to solve it lols just really looking for help as to why it wasn't spawning after the first wave.

Comment: Can you check if WaveCompleted is called ?

Comment: its not whats happening is i have them spawning and i can kill them but it dosen't show the WaveCompleted, and when you were saying how my timeBetweenWaves, i understand that part now what you were saying but, using the Time.Deltatime? or is that what i shouldn't use in my void update?

Comment: This is because state isn't to WAITING or EnemyIsAlive return true, try to find out why :)

Comment: so what you are saying i think im starting to understand but a question when in the Inspector and say i have killed one, the wave countdown is set to -0.003912315 and stays like that, is that relating to the issue of waiting? or is that a different issue im facing?

Comment: As it should be, because it's waiting to be reset when you complete the wave. I think the issue resides in your states. Try to show the state once you killed all enemies, shoud put you in the right way

Comment: dont know if this is what i should have added but, i put this and now waves are spawning back to back really fast XD                                
              bool EnemyIsAlive(){
        
        searchCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(searchCountdown <= 0f){


            searchCountdown = 1f;
            if(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Enemy") == null){


            return false;
            }
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }

Comment: after i kill them all it is in waiting state so i will try looking there

Comment: Hey so i think i did something by adding waveCountdown = timeBetweenWaves; to where bool EnemyIsAlive() and after they spawn in it goes back to the proper 5 in the wave countdown but doesn't change the state from waiting to counting to spawning, and since i think im going now in the right path what do you think i should look at now for it to go from waiting to counting and spawning?